# Passing integers to arrays within functions (without pointers)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, constants

I'm trying to create a magic square that will print four different grid sizes (5x5, 7x7, 9x9, 15x15).  The error I'm having is the array magsquare within the function tells me it needs a constant integer.  (I can't use pointers)  This is a class assignment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void magicSquare(int n){
int magsquare[n][n] = { 0 };    /*THIS is the error with [n][n]*/

int gridsize = n * n;
int row = 0;
int col = n / 2;

for (int i = 1; i <= gridsize; ++i)
{
    magsquare[row][col] = i;

    row--;
    col++;

    if (i%n == 0)
    {
        row += 2;
        --col;
    }
    else
    {
        if (col == n)
            col -= n;
        else if (row < 0)
            row += n;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        cout << setw(3) << right << magsquare[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;

}

}
int main(){
    int n = 5;
    magicSquare(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Indentation may look incorrect, but it's right.  Sorry.

Comment: Ease up yourself and use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead. ([I had a dream](http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/2015/02/i-have-dream-im-dreaming-of-so-called-c.html))

Comment: I can't use vectors or pointers for this code :/

Comment: Hey! I never was rude against the OP. Calling his/her teacher an _incompetent tw*t_  certainly didn't made that comment invalid (that was just telling facts I have to suffer from, with our day to day work)

Comment: As a side note, could anybody explain why his code works for me?

Comment: @Wolfgang.Finkbeiner Because some compilers support (as a proprietary extension) allocating arrays on the stack with their size based on other variables values on the stack. That's not guaranteed by standard c++/c though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure is because standard C++ cannot allocate dynamically sized array on the stack, as you are trying to do.

```
int magsquare[n][n];
```

As far as `magicSquare` is concerned `n` is only known at runtime and for an array to be allocated on the stack it's size must be known at compile time.

Use a 15 x 15 array.

```
int magsquare[15][15];
```

As long as you know this is the largest you'll ever need, you should be ok.

Alternatives (which you've already said you can't use)

- Use `new` to declare a 2d array of the required dimensions. (Remember to delete[] it though)
- Use `std::vector`

It may also be a good idea to add a check that n values over 15 or under 1 are rejected, otherwise you'll face undefined behaviour if any values outside of 1-15 are passed into the function.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much.  Such an easy fix.

Comment: No probs. You could accept the answer if its what you're after. You'll find with C/C++ a bit of a fudge can often make things a lot simpler.